# Azure Function App v4 + .NET 6.0 (in process) + Blob binding (not trigger) = Can't bind Blob to type error

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I'm having trouble getting this combination working, even in a hello world function. I want a function which consumes a table and blob, but not as triggers (trigger is timer).

When I run the function app locally I'm getting

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer'.
Possible causes:
 1) Tried binding to 'Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient, Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
 2) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs.Config.BlobsExtensionConfigProvider+MultiBlobContext, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
 3) Tried binding to 'System.IO.Stream, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
 4) Tried binding to 'Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlockBlobClient, Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
 5) Tried binding to 'Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.PageBlobClient, Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
 6) Tried binding to 'Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.AppendBlobClient, Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
 7) Tried binding to 'Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient, Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
 8) Tried binding to 'Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient, Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
```

To create this I did the following :

1. Create new function app project using .NET 6.0 in process
2. Created the following function :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run(
            [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
            [Blob("activity-events", Connection = "StorageAccountBlobEndpoint")] CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer,
            ILogger log

        )
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

Complete CSPROJ is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I want to have a table binding too in future which I understand precludes V 5.X of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.

I'm probably missing something basic here but if anyone can identify would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Microsoft.WindowsAzure` is the old namespace.  What version of the functions SDK are you using?  It'll be in the **.csproj** file under the `AzureFunctionsVersion` tag.  I assume it's v4 given that's the nuget package installed but just want to check.

Comment: Yep 4.1.0 of the SDK. I've edited the original post to have the complete CSPROJ and CS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK as expected it seems to have turned out to be fairly simple - instead of referencing `CloudBlobContainer` from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob`, I switched to referencing it from `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table`.

Side note : this unleashed an enormous pandora's box of other things I now need to fix in this existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the blob and table to be output bindings since your input/trigger binding is a timer?

Take a look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

I believe something along the lines of:

```
            public class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, 
        [Blob("activity-events", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "MyBlobConnString")] out Stream myblob,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        //DO SOMETHING WITH myBlob before function exits
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it has to be in the format I posted unfortunately, refactoring some existing code and don't have any time to pivot how it all works.